# Import react-bootstrap in sass

Tags: reactjs, sass, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to customize a react app in bootstrap.

inside src/custom.scss
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

however, is there any way to import react-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Customize Bootstrap
If you wish to customize the Bootstrap theme or any Bootstrap variables you can create a custom Sass file:
/* The following block can be included in a custom.scss

```
/* make the customizations */
$theme-colors: (
    "info": tomato,
    "danger": teal
);

/*import bootstrap to set changes */
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

... And import it on the main Sass file.

```
/* The following line can be included in a src/App.scss */

@import "custom";
```